# Android Preference Screen, change color behind title text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have changed the background color to my preference screen but the title bar is acting strange.

I have this as my theme set in the manifest for the preference activity as below:

```
<style name="PrefTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/activity_default_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

Which works, but the title bar now looks like this:

[image: Image with no color to background]

I have tried playing with a bunch of other properties to change it but can't find the correct one.

Thanks

Steve

Edit:

Looking at the edit text popups they have also changed

[image: Edit text]

I tried to change the popups with, but didn't work

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activity_default_bg_color</item>
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/activity_default_bg_color</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/activity_default_bg_color</item>
```

I had to use this instead

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activity_default_bg_color</item>
```

This fixed both the problems mentioned above.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks

Steve

Edit:

End Result:

[image]
[image]